# Django-Userena email backend

Tags: django, django-users

I am trying to set up [Django-Userena](http://www.django-userena.org/).

I have added the following line to `settings.py` file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'
```

Also tried with:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

When trying to sign up for a new account, I get this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/signup/

Module "django.core.mail.backends.smtp" does not define a "EmailBackEnd" class
```

I am pretty sure it's something obvious, but at this point, I can't figure out the problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post `EMAIL_HOST`, `EMAIL_PORT`, `EMAIL_HOST_USER`, `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`, and `EMAIL_USE_TLS` defined in your `settings.py`? And who is your mail service provider?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following  gmail settings in `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your-username@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Make sure the above  entries  should be in your `settings` file

If you have your own mail server then first install sendmail

Instead of using smtp.gmail.com which imposes lot many limitations, you can have your own mail server.

you can do it by installing your own mailserver:

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = "mail.mysmtpserver.somewhere"
#EMAIL_PORT = ""
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "my@login"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mypassword"
#EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your@mail.com'` to your settings and it should work.